# How do I configure or extend iTunes (on Mac OS X) to send a Growl notification when it's finished burning a CD?

Tags: macos, itunes, burning, compact-disc, growl

Is it possible to get a iTunes to send a (Mac OS X) Growl notification when it's finished burning a CD? (GrowlTunes doesn't do that.) How?

Update: Can an AppleScript query iTunes on whether it's finished burning?  Then an AppleScript could poll iTunes and issue a Growl notification when it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you have iTunes' source code in your possession.

You can probably use the `poll` option of the `drutil` command from a shell script.